# Where find Chromium Embedded Framework 1 (CEF1) binary

Tags: chromium-embedded

I'm looking for CEF1 binary files for Ubuntu, but i can find only CEF3 binary files.

Is CEF1 deprecated and no longer available for download?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CEF1 was retired quite a while ago, see http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10647

Comment: I need to use CEF with single process mode. Is there any way to do so with CEF3?

Comment: It's still there, though unsupported and not recommended.

Comment: I cannot find a pre-compiled build for linux

Comment: I can't find any Linux build. do you have direct link ?

Comment: There are 32bit and 64bit versions for every branch. I'd probably start with `2454` as it's the most up to date (though not officially released yet). Not sure what else I can say other than have another look, they're are Linux builds available on cefbuilds.com

Comment: This is not the direct answer to the question.

Comment: CEF1 is deprecated and to my knowledge is no longer available to download. If you have a link then by all means post it and I'll remove this answer.

Comment: CEF3 single process mode was removed since branch 3578.